# Implementing undo/redo on array of objects using vuex

Tags: arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects, vuex, undo-redo

I am trying to implement undo/redo in a complex application
This is how my history array looks.

```
[
{
  action:“added”,
  payload:{ 
    id:"32132132",
    data: "JSON.Stringify(JSON.parse(data))) initial data getting from initial app setup"
  }
},
{
  action:“updated”,
  payload:{ 
    id:"32132132",
    data: "getting the diff"
  }
},
{
  action:“deleted”,
  payload:{
    id:"32132132",
    data: "data"
  }
}
]
```

As far as I understood, the undo, redo works on a history index,
which will be changed based on undo (increment pointer) , redo (decrement pointer) concept.

Based on this approach I am calling a mutation where

```
apply(state,actiontype){
if(actiontype==undo){
           remove the respective objects
           pop(data) //pops the data out of other places in the application not the history
           historyindex++;
}else if(actiontype==redo){
           get the data from history
           unshift(data);
           historyindex–-;
}
}
```

I feel this is not the most efficient way to perform undo/redo operations, as it includes cloning objects and even it has to handle huge sets of data. Which might lead to freezing of the application I am still a newbie in vuejs, please do correct me if I am wrong,  is there any more efficient way to perform undo-redo operations ? or the right way to implement undo/redo in vuejs?.
Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider use some kind of data compress (like git does), with this you can continue using only the Vuex. Otherwise, consider use some local database as already recommended ;D

Answer (score 0):

you may want to connect your app to any simple database that store your previous object try firebase if it has no backend and make vuex just have the previous value but older ones saved to the firebase database by the mutation method in vuex